# Ultralimit extends limit of nets?

Tags: general-topology, filters, nets

> **Problem.** If $(x_i)$ is a net converging to a point $x$, show that $(x_i)$ converges to $x$ along any nonprincipal ultrafilter.

I will define these things below.

---

A **directed set** is a poset $(I,\leq)$ such that any two elements have an upper bound.

A **net** in a topological space $X$ is a function $I\rightarrow X$, where $I$ is a directed set. This is typically denoted $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ to indicate $i\mapsto x_i$. I will use $(x_i)$, omitting the index when convenient.

A **(classical) limit** of a net $(x_i)$ is a point $x\in X$ such that: for all neighborhoods $U$ of $x$, there exists an index $i_0\in I$ such that $x_i\in U$ for all $i\geq i_0$. Notation:
$$\lim_{i\in I} x_i = x$$

Now let $p$ be an ultrafilter on $I$. An **ultralimit** of $(x_i)$ is a point $x\in X$ such that: for all neighborhoods $U$ of $x$, the set $\{i\in I : x_i\in U\}$ belongs to $p$. Notation:
$$\lim_{i\rightarrow p} x_i = x$$
In a compact Hausdorff space, every net has a unique ultralimit along any ultrafilter, regardless of whether the classical limit exists. Now I claim that if the classical limit exists, then it is *equal* to the ultralimit along any (nonprincipal) ultrafilter.

> **Claim.** If $(x_i)$ has a classical limit $x$, then $x$ is also an ultralimit of $(x_i)$ (along any nonprincipal ultrafilter).

---

*Proof in the case of sequences*

I can prove this when $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is a sequence (*i.e.* $I=\mathbb{N}$). This simply because the "tail-end" $[i_0,\infty)$ is cofinite for all $i_0\in \mathbb{N}$, so it belongs to any nonprincipal ultrafilter. The argument generalizes to any directed set in which all tail-ends are cofinite.

Here are the details of the argument. Suppose $(x_n)$ converges classically to $x$; we must show that $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ along any nonprincipal ultrafilter $p$. For any neighborhood $U$ of $x$, there exists $n_0$ so that $x_n\in U$ for all $n\geq n_0$. Thus $\{n\geq 1 : x_n\in U\}$ contains the tail-end $[n_0,\infty)$. But since $[n_0,\infty)$ is cofinite, it belongs to $p$ since $p$ is nonprincipal. By upper-closure of ultrafilters, this implies $\{n\geq 1 : x_n\in U\}$ also belongs to $p$. QED.

---

I don't know how to generalize the above argument unless $(I,\leq)$ has the property that every tail-end is cofinite. This seems like a pivotal part of the argument though, so I suspect that my claim is not true in general. Any thoughts?

Comment: (Not exactly the same question, but the question there has stronger hypotheses and still a negative answer.)

Comment: Actually, I can give a stronger answer here relating to your comment about tail-ends being cofinite, so I'll reopen this.

Comment: I see. If $p$ is an ultrafilter containing every tail-end, then my argument still works. Nobody can guarantee that $p$ has this property in general. But it *does* work for sequences. Thanks!

Comment: This post on MathOverflow is related (at least to some extent): [What is a generalized limit?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/242307) The answer I posted there contains some references to some places where such limit is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is true *only* in the case when every tail-end of $(I,\leq)$ is cofinite, where (as you mention) the argument generalizes easily.  Indeed, suppose there is some $j\in I$ such that $A=\{i\in I:i\geq j\}$ is not cofinite, so $B=\{i\in I:i\not\geq j\}$ is infinite.  Consider a net $(x_i)$ which takes constant value $x$ on $A$ and constant value $y$ on $B$.  Then $(x_i)$ converges to $x$, but with respect to any ultrafilter containing $B$ it converges to $y$ (and thus not does not converge to $x$ if $y\neq x$ and $X$ is Hausdorff, for instance).  In particular, since $B$ is infinite, there exist nonprincipal ultrafilters which contain it.

The correct generalization is that the result applies to ultrafilters which contain every tail-end of $I$, rather than to nonprincipal ultrafilters.

Comment: You want $B$ to be the complement of $A$, so it should contain not only the elements $i$ that are $<j$ but also those that are incomparable with $j$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Right, of course.  I was originally thinking in terms of a counterexample that was totally ordered and didn't think to fix it.

Comment: Here is another remark. Let $(I,\leq)$ be a directed set in which every tail-end is infinite (so this discounts the pathological example $I=\mathbb{N}\sqcup\{\infty\}$). Then there is a nonprincipal ultrafilter containing every tail-end.

Comment: The proof relies on a lemma: if $\mathcal{A}$ is a collection of subsets of $I$ with the *infinite* finite intersection property --- *i.e.* for all $A_1\cap \cdots\cap A_n$ is infinite for all $A_1,\ldots,A_n\in \mathcal{A}$ --- then $\mathcal{A}$ is contained in a nonprincipal ultrafilter. This is a fun set-theoretic check. Now take $\mathcal{A}$ to be the collection of tail-ends.